# Easily find one stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio from 1000 in treeview?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Our database is about to reach 1000 stored procedures.  Although we were wise and created a good scheme for naming the stored procedures, hunting for the stored procedure you need can be a bit frustrating as you scroll and scroll and scroll.  If I know the exact name of the stored procedure I'm looking for, it would be great to identify it quickly and modify

For example, if I want to find p_Blah_Blah in the treeview and open it to modify it, is there a command to launch p_Blah_Blah in a new window for editing?  Or perhaps a plugin that limits the view of stored procedures to what you are searching for?  Anyone who wants to write a plugin?  :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can filter the tree, right click on "Stored Procedures" choose "Filter" and "Filter Settings".

As a general rule here we use naming conventions to do with context, for example all user sprocs are named: `usp_user_*`

Comment: They're not likely to rename 1000 procedures, especially with a satisfactory existing convention.  But +1 for the Filter advice.

Comment: +1 for Filter - however, in SQL Server, all system SPs are prefixed with sp_. When any SP is called which begins sp_ the system tries to find it in the master database first before searching the current database. You are creating a performance hit with your naming convention.

Comment: This does the trick and works with our current naming conventions.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: it depends on your version of SQL how you do this.

Comment: I actually meant usp_ but mistyped it seems, the point was putting context in the stored proc name.

Comment: our naming conventions work a bit like this...

gp_ = generated procedure
mp_ = maintenance procedure
rp_ = report procedure
p_ = plain old procedure

Filtering out the gp_ makes things a bit easy to navigate.

Answer (score 7):

Check out the redgate tools here, they have a free search tool that makes this kind of stuff a breeze:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

Answer (score 2):

In Management Studio 2005 you can right click on the stored procedures folder (and other folders too) to set a filter, then you can type in all, or part, of the names that you are looking for.

If you just want to know details of parameters (or rows for a table etc.) then in a query window you can type the objects name, highlight it, and press alt-F1 to call sp_Help on the object.

Answer (score 2):

EXEC sp_HelpText 'your procedure name'

then proceed to modifying it.

Comment: This is a great feature, but not 100% what I was looking for.  I will keep this one in the "bag-o-tricks" though.  Thanks!

Comment: I was actually looking for exactly how to list the stored proc and ended up at this question..so upvote even though it's not specifically for the original question.